Are the two definitions of positive operator acting on $L^{2}(\mu)$ equivalent?
Let $A$ be a linear bounded operator acting on the Hilbert space of square integrable functions for a given measure $\mu$. Consider the following definitions of positive operator:

Definition 1: $A$ is said to be positive iff $\langle A f , f \rangle \geq 0$ for all $f \in L^{2}(\mu)$.

Definition 2: $A$ is said to be positive iff $f \geq 0 \implies Af \geq 0$ for all $f \in L^{2}(\mu)$.


Are the two definitions equivalent?

Not equivalent. The matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
-1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
acting on $\ell_2^2$ satisfies Definition 1, but not definition 2.

And the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \ 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ satisfies 2 but not 1.
